# Anisotropic effect doesn't work (blender 4.0)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I faced with the problem that anisotropic effect doesn't applies neither using eevee renderer, nor cycles. Could you help me? File is attached

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works fine but you need to be in *Rendered* preview mode and in Cycles. The *Material* preview uses Eevee and *Anisotropic* doesn't work in Eevee (as indicated [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html)):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Anisotropy only works with cycles (as indicated [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html)). You need to be in render mode in order to use cycles. In the image you sent, you are in preview mode, so you'll have to switch modes

[image]

The default world scene is dark and unlit, so you wont see anything. Lighten your scene so you can see the effect

[image]